# JSON.parse & JSON.stringify handling long integers as strings

Tags: javascript, json

I have the problem, that I need to parse long integers in my API. Since I don't do anything arithmetically, it is the easiest to handle them as Strings. I tried [Bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/), but it starts complaining if numbers are longer than 15 characters. Unfortunately I have to handle them as well.

Since I don't do anything arithmetically with it and actually even store those numbers as String I would like a JSON Parser that parses too big numbers as Strings and is capable of also treat them as numbers in JSON.stringify.

I tried the stringify with a replacer function, but I could not get rid of the quotes around my number.

I also did not find a library, that just takes care of this issue.

#### Edit / Clarification

I want my big number to be a String in javascript, but a number in JSON (after JSON.stringify)

e.g. Object in Javascript

```
var myObj = {
    id: "89074987798719283473" // <-- String within javascript
}

var objString = JSON.stringify(myObj)
```

Now my objString should be

> {id: 89074987798719283473}

And NOT

> {id: "89074987798719283473"}

Comment: `but I could not get rid of the quotes around my number.` I thought you said you *wanted to treat them as strings*. Strings have quotes. If a number is too big to use as a number and you aren't doing math with it anyway, treat it as a string, always.

Comment: I think I did not explain myself, well enough. I added an example what I exactly want to achieve

Comment: That seems like an odd requirement which makes me wonder if you aren't dealing with an x-y problem. If other words you are trying to fix the problem in the wrong place. Generating json that you won't be able to parse again seems wrong. But if you must do it, remember json is a string and so all the normal string manipulation tools apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely must do this and really can't find a better place to handle this, then remember that JSON is just a string, and all the tools for string manipulation can be brought to bear on this problem. So you could do something like:

```js
var myObj = {
    id: "89074987798719283473" // <-- String within javascript
}

var json = JSON.stringify(myObj);   // this is {"id":"89074987798719283473"}

var numberJson = json.replace(/"id":"(\d+)"/,'"id":$1');    // this is now {"id":89074987798719283473}

console.log(numberJson);
```

Of course this is hacky and error prone as you have to be very careful about what you are matching (you might have other properties called `id` nested in your json that you don't want manipulated). If you wanted to make it a little more robust, you could append something the end of your `id` before you stringify to make it easier to find and replace it in the string.